# Setting focus on a ListBox item breaks keyboard navigation

Tags: wpf, listview, select, listbox, listboxitem

After selecting ListBox item programmatically it is needed to press down\up key **two times** to move the selection. Any suggestions?

View:

```
<ListBox Name="lbActions" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"
               Width="260" Height="180">
        <ListBoxItem Name="Open" IsSelected="true" Content="Open"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Name="Enter" Content="Enter"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Name="Print" Content="Print"></ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Code:

```
public View()
{
   lbActions.Focus();
   lbActions.SelectedIndex = 0; //not helps
   ((ListBoxItem) lbActions.SelectedItem).Focus(); //not helps either
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't set the focus to the ListBox... set the focus to the selected ListBoxItem. This will solve the "two keyboard strokes required" problem:

```
if (lbActions.SelectedItem != null)
    ((ListBoxItem)lbActions.SelectedItem).Focus();
else
    lbActions.Focus();
```

If your ListBox contains something else than `ListBoxItem`s, you can use `lbActions.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lbActions.SelectedIndex)` to get the automatically generated `ListBoxItem`.

---

If you want this to happen during *window initialization*, you need to put the code in the `Loaded` event rather than into the constructor. Example (XAML):

```
<Window ... Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    ...
</Window>
```

Code (based on the example in your question):

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbActions.Focus();
        lbActions.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ((ListBoxItem)lbActions.SelectedItem).Focus();
    }
```

Comment: I have already selected item in XAML "IsSelected="true". I provide additional selection in code, so it may be more obvious what I want to do "lbActions.SelectedIndex = 0;".

Comment: My answer still works, just put the code *after* the `SelectedIndex = 0`.

Comment: Don't work for me. Item selected, this is no a problem. Keyboard navigation not works correctly after.

Comment: Ah, only now I realized that you want *initial* focus (not focus in response to some button click). OK, I'll look into that.

Comment: Moving item selection code to the Windows Loaded event solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily in XAML too. Please note that this will set logical focus only.

For example:

```
<Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=itemlist, Path=SelectedItem}">
    <ListBox x:Name="itemlist" SelectedIndex="1">
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Four</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Five</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Six</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems that there are two levels of Focus for ListBox control: ListBox itself and ListBoxItem. Like Heinzi said, directly set Focus for the ListBoxItem will avoid the case that you have to click twice on direction key in order to go through all ListBoxItems.

I found out this after several hours work, now it works perfect on my APP.

Comment: [REVIEW] Hi DanielGao, I've voted down your submit, because it does no add anyhing to the answer Heinzi already gave. If you want to compliment Heinzi, better use the comments !