# How to set focus on listbox item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a defined list box like this:

```
var listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.Items.Add(1);        
listBox.Items.Add(2);
listBox.Items.Add(3);
```

And I want to set focus directly to an item in the listbox.

If I do this:

```
listBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
listBox.Focus();
```

The focus is set to the entire listBox, so if I press arrow down to move the selection to the item below, I have to press the arrow twice. First time the focus jumps from the entire listBox to the first item, and then when I can press the arrow again and the selection finally jumps down.

I want to set the focus directly to that first item, so I don't have to press the arrow twice.

Comment: use the ListBox SelectedValue property

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting focus on a ListBox item breaks keyboard navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223901/setting-focus-on-a-listbox-item-breaks-keyboard-navigation)

Comment: Hmm, i did the  ((ListBoxItem) listBox.SelectedItem).Focus();  but for some reason it has no effect and i still have to click twice. I guess i will have to solve it by simulating one key press.

Comment: Are you still having `listBox.focus();` somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 22):

```
var listBoxItem =  
   (ListBoxItem)listBox
     .ItemContainerGenerator
       .ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem);

listBoxItem.Focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar (if not equal) question [Setting focus on a ListBox item breaks keyboard navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223901/setting-focus-on-a-listbox-item-breaks-keyboard-navigation)

And the code (I don't mess with WPF so I can't guarantee this works, but it was accepted on the thread I linked so it might):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox.Focus();
    listBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ((ListBoxItem)listBox.SelectedItem).Focus();
}
```

Comment: @elgonzo Didn't see the WPF tag. Sorry about that :)

Comment: Looks much better (just remove the WinForms stuff in your answer) :) *WindowLoaded* is perhaps not the right time for doing this, entirely depending on when the listbox is initially populated with the first items...

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.  It seem to have no effect at all. (It still only selects the entire listbox)

Comment: @user3595338, see my last comment under your question.

Comment: Marcelo, remove `listBox.Focus();` from the code. I just noticed it now. This will most likely not work properly... (inside WPF, setting focus is a deferred action. For fun, you could put listbox.Focus at the end of the method and compare the different behaviour... ;) )

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter if the listBox.Focus(); is there or not since even if it is there, it would get overridden by the latter focus anyway. But to be sure, i tried to remove it anyway, but all it did was that the listbox didn't focused at all now.

Comment: @user3595338, you are mistaken with your assumption about how WPF does focus... if you don't have listbox.Focus() anymore and the problem persist, then whatever is going on in your code there is not related with focussing the listbox items. What you are experiencing are some side effects caused by your code, which i cannot speculate about since i do not know your code...

Comment: This won't work if the items are bound, via the `ItemsSource` property. In this scenario the selected item can't be cast to a ListBoxItem so you have to use @Robin's earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Focus.() on a listbox item. However you can select items which is pretty much the same thing as you are looking to do.   `listbox.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some explanation