# ListViewItem focus

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, focus

Using MVVM:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ... />
```

ViewModel:

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged { ... }

public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

public Item SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

Now if I change `SelectedItem`

```
// change
Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(...);
SelectedItem = Items.FirstOrDefault(item => ... some condition);
// notify view
OnPropertyChanged();
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
```

Then wanted item become properly selected, but it's not focused. Using keyboard navigation if I give focus to `ListView` somehow, then the very first item will become selected and focused.

How to give `SelectedItem` focus?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting focus on a ListBox item breaks keyboard navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223901/setting-focus-on-a-listbox-item-breaks-keyboard-navigation)

Comment: @R.Rusev, in MVVM `SelectedItem` is not `ListViewItem` (but `Item`). Hmm, so it's basically then question of how to get `ListViewItem` for given `Item`.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110679/how-to-set-focus-on-listbox-item as well

Comment: @R.Rusev, yes `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` should work. Again using MVVM I shouldn't do that in ViewModel. Hmm.. using `PropertyChanged` in View to monitor for `SelectedItem` changes and set focus to it?

Comment: Yes, subscribing for PropertyChanged should works.

Comment: @R.Rusev, well, I am having troubles to make it working. Sometimes `ListViewItem` is `null` (virtualizing? I don't want to turn it off) and focus is not set, so I need some other more reliable mechanic of how to set focus than `PropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to automatically focus selected `ListViewItem` when `ListView` has focus.

xaml:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="ListViewItem_Selected" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

view cs:

```
void ListViewItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (listView.IsFocused)
        (e.Source as ListViewItem)?.Focus();
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU I WAS STUCK ON THIS FOR LIKE 5 HOURS

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to put my control's behavior logic inside the control's code. What I mean is to extend standard controls in order to change their behavior in the way I need.

First of all I need to extend the `ListViewItem` control:

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class ListViewItem : System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem
    {
        protected override void OnSelected(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSelected(e);

            if (IsSelected)
            {
                Focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I need a `ListView` control which uses my `ListViewItem`:

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class ListView : System.Windows.Controls.ListView
    {
        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
        {
            return new ListViewItem();
        }
    }
}
```

So my XAML will become:

```
<local:ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ... />
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: The idea is interesting. I haven't thought about using custom control. Why do you check `IsSelected` value in selected event riser?

Comment: Since I want to set the focus on the current `ListViewItem` just if it is selected. Otherwise there is no need (in this case some other control will receive the focus).